# VOID code behind working. String return using Ajax not working. (Checking PayPal details)

Tags: c#, ajax, paypal

I'm trying to convert a void code behind call to PayPal which checks a users PayPal details, to an Ajax call to work in the background.

I'm struggling to

1. Turn from Void to a String to return the value for Ajax
2. When I do use my method of a string, it just times out - even if I set timeout to a ridiculously high number. Then it fails and just comes back as undefined.

Working code behind void code:

```
public async void checkAccAsync()
{
    userManager um = new userManager();
    var userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    um.Get(userID);
    var subid = um.ppID.Trim();
    var token = getToken();

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/" + subid))
        {

            var id = "";
            var nextPayment = "";
            var status = "";
            var payerEmail = "";
            var currency = "";

            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(res);



            id = obj2.id;

            nextPayment = obj2.billing_info.next_billing_time;
            if (nextPayment == null)
            {
                nextPayment = obj2.billing_info.last_payment.time;
                var nextPayment2 = Convert.ToDateTime(nextPayment);
                nextPayment2.AddMonths(1);
                nextPayment = nextPayment2.ToString();
            }
            status = obj2.status;
            status = status.ToLower();
            status = FirstLetterToUpper(status);
            payerEmail = obj2.subscriber.email_address;
            currency = obj2.shipping_amount.currency_code;
            um.updatePaypal_noIPN(id, status, "Regular", nextPayment, payerEmail, currency);

        }
    }
}
```

Ajax call with String (ideal method), **which isn't working**.

```
[WebMethod]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> CheckAccAsync()
{
    userManager um = new userManager();
    var userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    um.Get(userID);
    var subid = um.ppID.Trim();
    var token = getToken();

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/" + subid))
        {
            var id = "";
            var nextPayment = "";
            var status = "";
            var payerEmail = "";
            var currency = "";

            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            string res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(res);

            id = obj2.id;

            nextPayment = obj2.billing_info.next_billing_time;
            if (nextPayment == null)
            {
                nextPayment = obj2.billing_info.last_payment.time;
                var nextPayment2 = Convert.ToDateTime(nextPayment);
                nextPayment2.AddMonths(1);
                nextPayment = nextPayment2.ToString();
            }
            status = obj2.status;
            status = status.ToLower();
            status = FirstLetterToUpper(status);
            payerEmail = obj2.subscriber.email_address;
            currency = obj2.shipping_amount.currency_code;
            um.updatePaypal_noIPN(id, status, "Regular", nextPayment, payerEmail, currency);

            return status + ", "+payerEmail+", ";
        }
    }
}
```

And the jQuery which calls it:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/WebServices/checkPayPal.asmx/CheckAccAsync',
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError,
        timeout: 150000
    });
});

function OnSuccess(data, status) {
    alert(data.d);
}
function OnError(data, status) { // error 2
    alert(data.error)
        };
```

Why isn't my Ajax string method not working?

Comment: Please share the details from the Network tab in your browser. Specifically the details of the request being made (and the payload) and the response.

Comment: @mjwills "failed to load response data". Anything else specific you'd like me to provide & I can add to the question.